# Adding validation to notify user if they forget a value and getting an error that second and third values are null

Tags: javascript, html, validation, null

I am trying to add validation to see if user has forgotten an input. Currently trying to make sure i am obtaining the value they input and the first value for pilotName seems to work but the other values are showing up null.

The html i am using is

```
        <div id="launchForm">
            <form>
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
                    <label>Pilot Name <input type="text" name="pilotName" id="pilotName"/></label>
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
                    <label>Co-pilot Name <input type="text" name="copilotName"/></label>
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
                    <label>Fuel Level (L) <input type="text" name="fuelLevel"/></label> 
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
                    <label>Cargo Mass (kg) <input type="text" name="cargoMass"/></label>
                </div>
                <button id="formSubmit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and js file is

```
function init () {
//initialize button variable and assign it to html element
let submitFormButton = document.getElementById("formSubmit");
submitFormButton.addEventListener("click", preventDefault);

//validation function to perform if button is clicked
function preventDefault(){
   let pilotNameInput = document.getElementById("pilotName");
   let copilotNameInput = document.getElementById("copilotName");
   let copilotNameInput = document.getElementById("copilotName");
   let fuelLevelInput = document.getElementById("fuelLeveL");
   let cargoMassInput = document.getElementById("cargoMass");


   console.log(pilotNameInput.value);
   console.log(copilotNameInput.value);
   console.log(fuelLevelInput.value);
   console.log(cargoMassInput.value);
}
}

window.onload = init;
```

right now only pilot name is logging to the console while the rest are saying they are null even if i try them individually it seems pilotname is the only one registering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added "id" attribute to other fields. try adding "id" like below:

```
<div id="launchForm">
    <form>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
            <label>Pilot Name <input type="text" name="pilotName" id="pilotName" /></label>
        </div>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
            <label>Co-pilot Name <input type="text" name="copilotName" id="copilotName"/></label>
        </div>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
            <label>Fuel Level (L) <input type="text" name="fuelLevel"  id="fuelLevel" /></label>
        </div>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
            <label>Cargo Mass (kg) <input type="text" name="cargoMass"  id="cargoMass" /></label>
        </div>
        <button id="formSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As your code stands validation does not work for any of the inputs.

You didn't have the attribute *id* set to any of your elements by which you are trying to access the element. You can use `querySelector()` with *name* attribute.

You can use *input* elements default [**`required`**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-input-required-attribute/) attribute.

```js
function init () {
//initialize button variable and assign it to html element
let submitFormButton = document.getElementById("formSubmit");
submitFormButton.addEventListener("click", preventDefault);

//validation function to perform if button is clicked
function preventDefault(){
   let pilotNameInput = document.querySelector("[name=pilotName]");
   let copilotNameInput = document.querySelector("[name=copilotName]");
   let fuelLevelInput = document.querySelector("[name=fuelLevel]");
   let cargoMassInput = document.querySelector("[name=cargoMass]");


   console.log(pilotNameInput.value);
   console.log(copilotNameInput.value);
   console.log(fuelLevelInput.value);
   console.log(cargoMassInput.value);
}
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="launchForm">
  <form>
      <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
          <label>Pilot Name <input type="text" name="pilotName" id="pilotName" required/></label>
      </div>
      <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
          <label>Co-pilot Name <input type="text" name="copilotName" required/></label>
      </div>
      <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
          <label>Fuel Level (L) <input type="text" name="fuelLevel" required/></label> 
      </div>
      <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
          <label>Cargo Mass (kg) <input type="text" name="cargoMass" required/></label>
      </div>
      <button id="formSubmit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another much easier way to check if the user has filled all required fields. Just add the `required` attribute to the input tag, like so:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 8 0;">
    <label>Pilot Name <input type="text" name="pilotName" id="pilotName" required/></label>
</div>
```